# Initializing entire array with memset

Tags: c++, arrays, memset

I have initialised the entire array with value 1 but the output is showing some garbage value. But this program works correctly if i use 0 or -1 in place of 1. So are there some restrictions on what type of values can be initialised using memset.

```
 int main(){
    int a[100];
    memset(a,1,sizeof(a));
    cout<<a[5]<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: yup    it works with -1 . you can try it

Comment: You should probably first figure out what `sizeof(a)` does, and then you should figure out what is the type of the third argument of `memset()`. This should clear it up. PS. Don't do this in C++, it is unnecessary, and as you see, **wrong**.

Comment: If you have a modern compiler, you might want to try `std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 1);`

Comment: Your code isn't C++, it's C. If you really use a C++ compiler, don't write C code.

Answer (score 7):

memset, as the other say, sets every byte of the array at the specified value.

The reason this works with 0 and -1 is because both use the same repeating pattern on arbitrary sizes:

```
(int) -1 is 0xffffffff
(char) -1 is 0xff
```

so filling a memory region with `0xff` will effectively fill the array with -1.

However, if you're filling it with `1`, you are setting every byte to `0x01`; hence, it would be the same as setting every integer to the value `0x01010101`, which is very unlikely what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Memset fills bytes, from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset):

> Converts the value ch to unsigned char and copies it into each of the first count characters of the object pointed to by dest.

Your `int` takes several bytes, e.g. a 32bit int will be filled with 1,1,1,1 (in base 256, endianess doesn't matter in this case), which you then falsly interpreted as a "garbage" value.

Comment: Specifically `0x01010101` which is what you'll be forming in each `a` is `16843009` decimal, which I predict is the "garbage" value you're seeing. `-1` "works" (for the wrong definition of "works") because it fills the array's memory with 0xff and 0xffffffff is the 32-bit representation of `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers have explained `std::memset` already. But it's best to avoid such low level features and program at a higher level. So just use the Standard Library and its C++11 `std::array`

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 100> a;
a.fill(1);
```

Or if you prefer C-style arrays, still use the Standard Library with the `std::fill` algorithm as indicated by @BoPersson

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int a[100];
std::fill(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 1);
```

In most implementations, both versions will call `std::memset` if it is safe to do so.

Comment: little typo, should be std::end(a)

Comment: @karsten tnx, fixed

Answer (score -2):

memset is an operation that sets **bits**.

If you want to set a value use a for-loop.

Consider a 4-bit-integer:

Its value is 1 when the bits are 0001 but memset sets it to 1111