# How to use memset to fill in max value for an array?

Tags: c++, memset

Here is my code, I would need to fill in every element in the 2d array with the maximum size ( INT_MAX), however, my code was unable to work properly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[10][10];
    memset(arr,INT_MAX, sizeof (arr));
    cout << arr[0][3];
//output = -1 instead of 2147483647


}
```

How do I modify my code such that I will be able to fill in an array with the max values?

Comment: `memset` writes bytes, `INT_MAX` is not a byte. I would just write a for loop.

Comment: But your code would work if you changed `int arr[10][10];` to `unsigned arr[10][10];` and changed `INT_MAX` to `UCHAR_MAX`.

Comment: @john While technically true (for most reasonable architectures) I'm sure the reasons why are beyond James' current understanding and it likely would confuse them more than that it helps.

Comment: See some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3948290/509868).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693135/initializing-entire-array-with-memset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ Standard Library has a function [fill_n](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) to fill arrays with `n` values.

```
#include <algorithm>
...
std::fill_n(&arr[0][0], 100, INT_MAX);
```

The number of values may be brittle here - if you change the size of the array in future, you have to remember to change the hard-coded `100` to a new correct value.

It's good enough for a quick hack. If you need something with long-term value, use the idea in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63315283/509868) to a similar question.